# Disqus 2012 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPropertyValue' of null" on Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, disqus

Here at my company we are working hard to deliver a nice comment experience using the amazing Disqus widget.

Our site is totally AJAX based, using requirejs, jquery and backbone for the most.

We've already added the Disqus widget on the pages where we need it. During a page change we of course destroy the div where Disqus widget lives and we instantiate again all the stuff.

Everything is fine with the old widget, on every browser. The problem occurs activating the Disqus 2012's widget, that do not appear with the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of null", on Safari and Chrome. Firefox works great.

Here is the code involved:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/config',
  'models/book'
], function(_, Backbone, config) {

    App.Models.Disqus = Backbone.Model.extend({
        bookObj: null,

        initialize: function(options){
            console.log("discus.initialize()");
            var _this=this;

            _this.bookObj= new App.Models.Book({id: options.id});
            _this.bookObj.fetch({
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(model,response){
                    (typeof DISQUS == 'undefined')?_this.initDisqus():_this.resetDisqus();              }
            });

        },

        initDisqus: function(){
            console.log("discus.init()");
            disqus_shortname=config.get('DISQUS_ID');
            disqus_title = this.bookObj.get('content').title; 
            disqus_config = function (){
                // this.page.identifier = _this.id;
                // this.page.url = document.URL;
                this.language = config.get('LANG');
            };
            require(['http://'+disqus_shortname+'.disqus.com/embed.js'], function(){});
        },

        resetDisqus: function(){
            console.log("discus.reset()");
            var _this=this;
            DISQUS.reset({
                reload: true,
                config: function(){
                    this.page.identifier = _this.id;
                    this.page.url = document.URL;
                    this.page.title = _this.bookObj.get('content').title;
                    this.language = config.get('LANG');
                }
            });
        }

    });

    return App.Models.Disqus;
});
```

If you need more information feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance,
Giorgio

OK guys, solved in this way:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/config',
  'models/book'
], function(_, Backbone, config) {

    App.Models.Disqus = Backbone.Model.extend({
        bookObj: null,

        initialize: function(options){
            console.log("discus.initialize()");
            var _this=this;
            _this.bookObj= new App.Models.Book({id: options.id});
            _this.bookObj.fetch({
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(model,response){
                    //(typeof DISQUS == 'undefined')?_this.initDisqus():_this.resetDisqus();

                    delete DISQUS;

                    disqus_shortname = config.get('DISQUS_ID');
                    disqus_identifier = _this.id;
                    disqus_url = document.URL;         
                    disqus_title = _this.bookObj.get('content').title;

                    (function() {
                        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
                        dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
                    })();

                }
            });
        },
    });

    return App.Models.Disqus;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [DISQUS.reset documentation](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107) states, you need to reset the identifier and URL for the Disqus thread. This is done via two variables provided in the documentation: `this.page.identifier` and `this.page.url`. Right now you're resetting the page title and language in Disqus. Try resetting the identifier and URL instead.

Comment: Please note everything is working properly on Firefox with Disqus 2012, also working on any browser with the old plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, but the solution above (deleting DISQUS and reloading the script on the page) does not work in strict mode.  Attempting to delete DISQUS results in the error "Delete of an unqualified identifier in strict mode."

I solved the issue by making sure I was never removing the container that Disqus attaches itself to, which I was doing when swapping out the post with the post newly loaded via ajax.  Odd that it worked in Firefox without this fix, but it works everywhere now.